# Assign a value to character string

Tags: r

I have responses to a survey in my `data.frame(Analysis)` that include:
`Q1 <- c("Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Neither", "Agree", "Neither")`
I wish to assign a value to each response, based upon their level. For example, `"Strongly Agree"` receives a 2 whilst `"Agree"` receives a score of 1. My desired output would be:
`Q1 <- c("Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Neither", "Agree", "Neither")`
`Q1_Score <- c(1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 0)`
This seems like an simple question but I am having difficulty in finding an answer!
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `revalue` from the `plyr` package to create a new factor column in your `Analysis` data frame with the levels renamed:

```
library(plyr)
Analysis$Q1_Score <- revalue(Analysis$Q1,
               c("Strongly Agree"="2", "Agree"="1", "Neither"="0", "Disagree"="-1"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could put the values and the codes in a separate dataframe and then use `match` to get them into your main dataframe :

```
dat <- data.frame(Q1,Q1_Score)

Analysis$Q1_Score <- dat$Q1_Score[match(Analysis$Q1, dat$Q1)]
```

Comment: I voted the answer to the use of the `plyr` package but I also like your answer using the base of R. Thank you.

Comment: Or even just `c("Strongly Agree"=2, "Agree"=1, "Neither"=0, "Disagree"=-1)[Q1]`

Answer (score 4):

You can order them appropriately in a factor variable, then convert to numeric like so:

```
Q1 <- factor(Q1, levels=c("Disagree","Neither","Agree","Strongly Agree"))
as.numeric(Q1)-2
#[1]  1  2 -1  0  1  0
```

You subtract 2 because the lowest factor level is stored as 1, and you want the lowest level to be -1.

Alternatively, a one-liner that returns a factor variable instead of numerics:

```
factor(Q1, levels=c("Disagree","Neither","Agree","Strongly Agree"), labels=c(-1,0,1,2))
#[1] 1  2  -1 0  1  0 
#Levels: -1 0 1 2
```